# Retrieve all data using eloquent laravel

Tags: mysql, database, join, eloquent

I want to ask about how to retrieve all data in laravel

I have tables like this

**Corp**

```
corp_id
corp_name
```

**Subsidiary**

```
subsidiary_id
corp_id
subsidiary_name
```

**Customer PIC**

```
cust_pic_id
corp_id
subsidiary_id
cust_name
cust_phone
cust_address
cust_email
```

Each model like this

**corp model**

```
protected $table= 'corps';
public function CustomerPIC()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CustomerPIC');
}
```

**subsidiary model**

```
protected $table = 'subsidiaries';

public function CustomerPIC()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CustomerPIC');
}
```

**customer PIC model**

```
protected $table = 'customer_P_I_CS';

public function corp()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Corp');
}

public function subsidiary()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subsidiary');
}
```

and I have a controller

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    $getData = CustomerPIC::with(['Corp','Subsidiary'])->get();


    return response()->json([
        'data'=>$getData
    ]);
}
```

The question is, why I get the return without corp_name and subsidiary_name. and there is corp:NULL and subsidiary: NULL even I don't have that row

Which is there is no corp_name and subsidiary_name?

I want to return all of data.

Thank you for read it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load relationships with lowercase (same as you defined relationships):

```
$getData = CustomerPIC::with(['corp','subsidiary'])->get();
```